# How to write a data to a text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, file-handling

I am a knew to python and I started my first codes in Python but I can not write my data to a text file. Can anyone help me in writing my data here to a text file:

I am using Python 3.4

```
 In [66]:data
 Out[66]: 
                                  var1         var2
 20:22:49.999985        0.2160       0.1720
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
file = open('filename', 'w');
file.write(data.to_string());    // if data is a pandas.DataFrame object
file.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`open('out.txt', 'w').write(data)`

Comment: It is supposed to write text to text file:) So you must convert you type to string.