# How to put an array of strings with two variables into a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, text-classification, naivebayes

I'm trying to make a text classifier app. I have an array of strings which contains two parameters separated by comma like below:

```
pos_tweets = [('I love this car', 'positive'),
              ('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
              ('I feel great this morning', 'positive')]
```

And with that array of strings I can execute this code:

```
tweets = []
for (words, sentiment) in pos_tweets:
    words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in words.split() if len(e) >= 3] 
    tweets.append((words_filtered, sentiment))
print(tweets)
```

**with output:**

```
[(['love', 'this', 'car'], 'positive'), (['this', 'view', 'amazing'], 'positive'), (['feel', 'great', 'this', 'morning'], 'positive')]
```

What I'm trying to do is to put that array of strings into a text file and still able to execute the code with the same output as above.

Comment: Please share the steps you've taken so far in trying to write to a text file, and specify which part you need help with. If you're looking for an answer to the question "How to write text to a file in python" I'd recommend taking a look at other questions posted like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499257/how-to-write-a-data-to-a-text-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a text file where every line contains an element in your pos_tweets array. So in

pos_tweets.txt

```
I love this car, positive
This view is amazing, positive
```

Then you can read in each line with

```
import csv

tweets = []
with open('pos_tweets.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        words = row[0]
        sentiment = row[1]
        words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in words.split() if len(e) >= 3] 
        tweets.append((words_filtered, sentiment))
```

Answer (score 0):

to output your list to the txt file, you can use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module

I can't see how you can have the same output after reading from the txt file, but you can do it with very small modification in the current code.

to output the list to the text file, you can do:

```
with open('outfile', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(tweets, fp)
```

to read from it, you can do:

```
with open('outfile', 'rb') as fp:
    pos_tweets = pickle.load(fp)

for (words, sentiment) in pos_tweets:
    if type(words) == list:
        words = ' '.join(words)
    words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in words.split() if len(e) >= 3]
    tweets.append((words_filtered, sentiment))
```

With the above modified piece of code iterating through to `pos_tweets`, you can either work with the hardcoded tweets or from the ones read from the txt file.

Here's the complete code:

```
import pickle

pos_tweets = [('I love this car', 'positive'),
              ('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
              ('I feel great this morning', 'positive')]


def get_tweets(p_tweets):
    tweets = []
    for (words, sentiment) in p_tweets:
        if type(words) == list:
            words = ' '.join(words)
        words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in words.split() if len(e) >= 3]
        tweets.append((words_filtered, sentiment))
    return tweets


t = get_tweets(pos_tweets)

print(t)
with open('outfile', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(t, fp)

with open('outfile', 'rb') as fp:
    pos_tweets = pickle.load(fp)

t = get_tweets(pos_tweets)
print(t)
```